# Glassfish increase maxParameterCount

Tags: java, glassfish-3

We have a page on an application deployed in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 that has over 10,000 fields (both hidden and displayed) that get submitted to the server. When the page is submitted, the server logs spit out:

`WARNING: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request([10,000]) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.`

I've seen other posts on increasing it for JBoss using a system property on startup, but that doesn't work here. I've also tried setting that property on various connector XML attributes in domain.xml without any success, nor have I been able to find any UI control in the admin where that would be set.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that it is a POST request. They're not being submitted through a GET, it's a form submission that sends them.

Comment: @MichaelWard were you able to find a solution? Could you post it here if you did?

Comment: We have not been able to find a resolution for increasing the parameter count. We worked around it by collecting all the fields in Javascript and submitting a JSON string in a single variable and then unserializing it on the server. I would still love to know how to increase that parameter count, though, as it will definitely come up again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put the answer here for public knowledge, but it was someone else who I know who figured it out:

---

I changed web-core.jar to be web-core.zip and then opened the zip and went into the org/apache/catalina/connector folder. I extracted the Connector.class file and opened it in a hex editor, searched for 0x2710 (10,000) and changed it to 0xFFFF (-1) Then I copied the Connector.class back into the zip file and renamed back to .jar

I also opened the jar with java-decompiler to verify that the java code did actually look correct after manually editing the class file.